# Many to one NAT on Fortigate

Tags: nat

I am able to configure the one to one NAT (VIP) in Fortigate. but it seems many to one NAT is not possible.

We dont want to use the interface IP as NAT address. we want to assign another IP as the NAT address

External: 192.168.2.1
Internal: 192.168.1.1

we want use 192.168.2.2 as the NAT ip for 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Load Balancing feature of FortiOS.
VIP are more for one-to-one NAT or for port translation.

Answer (score 0):

Found that Overload is the answer.

Policy & Objects >> IP Pools >> create your IP Pools select the overload option .
go to the policy you want to NAT, inside the policy and under Firewall / Network Options, select Dynamic IP and select the IP Pools you just created.